# Pisugar3 との通信で Expected b'battery_v' but got b'battery: ...' というエラーが出る

Tags: python, python3, raspberry-pi

ラズベリーパイにpisugar3というUPSを取り付けており、5秒おきにpisugarから電圧とバッテリー容量を取得するという内容です。

プログラム実行の最初はうまくいくのですが、20分くらい動いたあとにエラーを返されます。（写真参照）どこか構文に問題があるのだと思うのですが、どこが悪いのか見当がつかないのでよろしくお願いいたします。

[image: エラーの画面]

参考スクリプト

[github PiSugar.py](https://github.com/PiSugar/pisugar-server-py)

**コード**

```
from pisugar import *
import datetime
import csv
import time


conn, event_conn = connect_tcp('raspberrypi.local')
s = PiSugarServer(conn, event_conn)

#s.register_single_tap_handler(lambda: print('single'))pisugarのgithubに記載されていた内容この文章が理解できていない。
#s.register_double_tap_handler(lambda: print('double'))この文章が理解できていない。


#csv設定
path = open(r"data/log.csv",'a',newline = '')
f = csv.writer(path)
writer = f


#取得時間間隔
inter = 5#インターバル時間を設定（秒）

list = ''

def writecsv():

#pisugar_API
    batplug = s.get_battery_power_plugged()#給電方式
    batlevel = s.get_battery_level()#バッテリー残量
    v = s.get_battery_voltage()#電圧

#時間設定
    dt_nowrow = datetime.datetime.now()
    dt_now = dt_nowrow.strftime('%Y年%m月%d日 %H:%M:%S')
    list = [dt_now,batplug,batlevel,v]
    writer.writerow(list)
    print(list)


#csv,書き込み
writer.writerow(['Time Stamp','給電','バッテリー残量','電圧'])
while True:
    shoutdownlevel = s.get_battery_level()#シャットダウン因子

    writecsv()
    time.sleep(inter)
    
    if (shutdownlevel < 10):
        break
```

Comment: エラーメッセージは写真では無く文字列として、質問に貼り付けるようにして下さい。SSH で接続している場合はコピペできると思います。

Answer (score 0):

製品の知識が有る方が少なそうで、回答が得られ難いと思いますので、推測を含めて回答します。

Pythonの構文に問題は見つかりません。おそらく、実際に間違った応答が製品から返されているのでしょう。 あるいは、`pisugar-server` という製品との通信を仲立ちしているプログラムにバグが有る、Pythonのモジュールとバージョンが有っていない、などかも知れません。

一般的には、こういったエラー（もしかしたらバグ）の安易な回避策として、

- 同時接続を避ける
- 通信の間隔を開ける
- 定期的に再接続や再起動をする

などが有ります。

また、質問のケースのように、通信の結果により例外が発生するライブラリの場合は、`try` 文で[例外を処理](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)し、エラーなどに対処することが出来ます。

Answer (score 0):

@mjy様
ありがとうございます。

回避策行いましたが、うまくいきませんでした。そのためtry文でエラーを回避して実行するように書き直したらうまくデータ取得ができました。
解決しました。ありがとうございます。